# Harmonic mean for averaging predictions?

Tags: predictive-models, mean, model-averaging, harmonic-mean

I have 14 different predictions about each observation in my dataset and I want to compute an overall prediction for each observation based on these. Would it be better to use the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) instead of the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean)?

Comment: Why not using a median instead of these both? Here you could benefit from its robustness against outliers (in your context some very low predictions).

Comment: Can you explain what you think would be the advantage of using harmonic mean? Some context would be useful.